# bluetooth headset connected but not listed as output

Tags: audio, bluetooth

**Arch up to date with 6.1.1-arch1-1 kernel**

This headset connects automatically on reboot but it does not appear as an audio device.I had an older model of this headset that was working as expected until a ninja toddler decided to inspect its construction. So the system does have the basic dependencies and configuration but there is a trouble here.

```
> bluetoothctl
Agent registered
AdvertisementMonitor path registered
[DEL] Device B0:C0:90:DE:B1:4E B0-C0-90-DE-B1-4E
[DEL] Device 74:2F:68:83:C8:B3 asgl
[DEL] Device 0C:96:E6:11:04:08 XBR-65X800G
[JBL LIVE660NC-LE]# devices
Device 6B:2D:7E:53:0A:1C JBL LIVE660NC-LE
Device C6:4E:63:DE:16:24 UniversalFoldableKb
[JBL LIVE660NC-LE]#
```

But then

```
:> pacmd list-sources | grep -E 'index|name|card' 
* index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6023110000 irq 170"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.name = "Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        
 :> pacmd list-sinks | grep -E 'index|name|card'
   * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
        alsa.name = "DELL U2419H"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6023110000 irq 170"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.name = "Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "DELL U2419H"
```